# carousel items randomly change position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I've got a jQuery carousel with 6 individual items scrolling from left to right. The scroll function works as it should, however I've noticed that 2 of the items seem to change vertical position(+/- 15px) at random.

The HTML looks ok to me, I'm not sure what else could be causing the problem?

Comment: You have some `<p>` tags mixed in with the `<li>` items in your carousel

Comment: @Mathias Unfortunately this is something Wordpress seems to generate on it's own; I definitely did not add them myself.

Comment: Can you edit the source? When I use view-source, the opening `ul` is contained in a `<span>` and  `<p>` tag. `<p><span style="line-height: 1.5em;"><div class="list_carousel list_carousel_center"><ul id="caroufred-41"></span></p>`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the p after the first li

```
<p style="width: 320px;"></p>
```

Comment: That line doesn't appear in my source code - pastebin.com/ZLBmquxL

Comment: it is inserted by the carousel then, look at the carousel.js

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this paragraph is necessary for something else in your code, but it doesn't appear to serve a purpose and removing it will fix the problem you're describing.

[image: paragraph problem]